# How to compare users localStorage / cookie data

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, local-storage, game-development

Im working on a little web game right now and I want to make a leaderboard, to store all user info ive been using localStorage, I want to be able to constantly check if one users money is greater than the highscore, if it is set the highscore to their money and username(The idea here is that everyone can see the highscore so when it updates everyone sees that variable)

Ive tried to find online resources about how to compare and contrast cookies / localStorage among users but I cant find anything that really helps

Comment: The leaderboard needs to be stored on the server, local storage only contains data for that user.

Comment: Please include the code that you tried in the question.